# Unknown provider error when testing a angular factory using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to test a angular "service" (actually implemented using factory) using jasmine, and getting the following error:

```
collectionService should contain collectionService
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: collectionServiceProvider <- collectionService http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$injector/unpr?p0=collectionServiceProvider%20%3C-%20collectionService in file:///C:/workspaces/angular/angular-1.2.1.js (line 78)
```

Here is the source:

```
'use strict';

var collectionMockData = {};
var collectionMockErrorData = {};

angular.module('gid.services.collectionMockService', ['ngMockE2E']).run(function($httpBackend, $resource) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/collection/v1/1234567890').respond(function(method, url, data, headers){
        return [200, collectionMockData, {}];
    });
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/collection/v1/1234567891').respond(function(method, url, data, headers){
        return [500, collectionMockErrorData , {}];
    });
});

angular.module('gid.services.collectionService', [ 'ngResource', 'gid.services.collectionMockService' ])
.factory('collectionService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    var collectionData = null;
    var collectionResource = $resource('/api/collection/v1/:shopperId', { 'shopperId': '@id' });
    return {
        getcollection: function (callback) {
            collectionResource.get({ 'shopperId': '1234567890' }).$promise
            .then(function (data) {
                callback(data);
            }).catch(function (data) {
                callback(data);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here is the test:

```
'use strict';

describe('collectionService', function() {

    beforeEach(function () { 
        angular.module('gid.services.collectionService');
    });


    it('should contain collectionService', inject(function (collectionService) {
        expect(collectionService).not.to.equal(null);

    }));

});
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

I am mocking the REST API in the source itself, since the backend REST API implementation is not available.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Maybe: beforeEach(module('gid.services.collectionService'));

Comment: Have you included all your files in your `karma.config.js`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
angular.module('gid.services.collectionService');
```

You should use either

```
angular.mock.module('gid.services.collectionService');
```

Or shortand

```
module('gid.services.collectionService');
```